# Prevent Nexus from pulling blocked package metadata

Tags: proxy, repository, nexus, nexus3

The Nexus3 routing feature will allow you to block a package from an upstream repo, but the blocked package will be included in the group metadata because it was merged from upstream repo metadata. This means if the blocked package of the proxy repo has a higher version than an internal, similarly named repo, Nexus will still suggest the blocked package, but simply not allow it to be downloaded.

How can I exclude the blocked package from the group metadata?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For python, it worked out to simply block the path of the package and the path of the metadata for the proxy, for example, the routing rule looks like:

```
/packages/ci-tools/.*
/simple/ci-tools/.*
```

This obvoiusly only works if the repo has separate package metadata files.

Answer (score 1):

There was just a report of this in the Nexus Repository Manager JIRA (see https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-24823).  You can follow and vote for a Sonatype solution.
I do not believe there is one in product otherwise at the moment.

Comment: Thanks, it would be preferred if this was more baked into the application.

Comment: @scader Agree, I can only provide the links and hope people vote=)